# Use X-editable for Bootstrap to send values to post.php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap and decided to use X-editable with it. I put in all the necessary files and it works fine except that I want to pass values to `post.php` where I want PHP to process `$_POST["value"]`.

Markup of the editable element is

```
<a href="#" id="example">Example</a>
```

I call it like this

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

  $('#example').editable({
  type: 'text',
  pk: 1,
  url: 'post.php',
  title: 'Enter example'
   });
});
```

I used [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) as an inline editor in which I passed on values to a php file with no problems and I would like to do so with X-editable but I can't seem to do it.

How do I pass the values to `post.php` so I can use php to manipulate the data?

Comment: The code you have above should already be passing the values to post.php. Have you tried printing out the $_POST array? Do you have any javascript errors when you check your browser's console?

Comment: @frostyterrier I tried print, print_r, var_dump, echo but I can't seem to manipulate what get's passed to post.php.
I left post.php completely empty and it still worked as before. Only when I delete post.php I get an error but other than that the contents of post.php seem to be irrelevent as long as it's there.
I checked the console and there are errors but they relate to css properties like box-sizing and the like.
I use FF 18.0 but have the same problem in Chrome.

Comment: That's very strange. Your code worked fine for me and I use X-editable for this type of thing often. There's nothing above that would prevent it from working. Have you tried using the exact files from this example? https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/tree/gh-pages/backend-samples/php Did those work?

Comment: @frostyterrier I tried that first but it didn't work. I use XAMPP and I though maybe the rewrite rules could have something to do with it so I removed them but it didn't help. Could you send me an example that works for you so I could test it? I use bootstrap for pretty much everything I do and I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: I don't know how to send you an example on here apart from adding an answer or linking you to external code, and this isn't an answer so here are some links: The HTML file: http://chopapp.com/#4dlbk2w3 The PHP file: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/blob/gh-pages/backend-samples/php/post.php I have tested these files and they work for me. I'm using MAMP on OS X with Chrome and Firefox. When I view my console this is the output I get from the ajax call: `Array
(
    [name] => example
    [value] => Example test
    [pk] => 1
)`

Comment: @frostyterrier Thanks for the help. I'm pretty new to ajax and don't really know my way around. I was able to pass the values but I have trouble updating entries. I tried the following in post.php

$id = $_POST["id"];
$value = $_POST["value"]:
$pk = $_POST["pk"];
$query = "UPDATE table SET ".$id." = '".$value."' WHERE key = '".$pk."'";
$dbHandler->exec($query);

Everything is properly escaped and it connects to post.php because when I put in the values in post.php myself it updates the entries. It just can't seem to get the values. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @frostyterrier Thanks for all the help. I played around with the console and found out what was bugging me. I finally got it to work.

Comment: Okay great, I'm glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a href="#" id="example">Example</a>`

you must add data-name=""

`<a href="#" id="example" data-name="db-col-name">Example</a>`

so when you access it in post.php, you can do like this:

`$name = $_POST['name']` // $_POST['name'] catches the data-name value

`$pk= $_POST['pk']`  // the pk(primary key) that you assigned

`$value= $_POST['value']` // the new value after you use the inline edit

after that you could do something like this

`if(!empty($value)) {`

`$result = mysql_query('update users set '.mysql_escape_string($name).'="'.mysql_escape_string($value).'" where user_id = "'.mysql_escape_string($pk).'"');`

```
} else {
    header('HTTP 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
    echo "This field is required!";
} `
```

credits to the makers of x-editable 
its from their php sample
[more info here](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/tree/gh-pages/backend-samples/php)

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like this

```
<a href="#" id="roll_no" data-type="text" data-pk="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-url="ajax.php" ><?php echo $row['roll_no']; ?></a>
```

Reference :- [jQuery x editable tutorial](https://www.mycodingtutorials.com/?p=259)